# AVR - ATmega8A - External Interrupt - Sometimes odd behaviour

Tags: c, external, interrupt, avr

I am currently working on a MCU unit which will respond to external interrupts in order to perform specific tasks.
The controller I am using: ATmega8A.

The external interrupt is defined as followed:

```
PORTD |= 0x04;                          //Activate pull up resistor of PD2
GICR |= (1 << INT0);                    //Enable INT0
MCUCR |= (1<<ISC00);                    //INT0 is executed on every edge
```

The ISR:

```
ISR (INT0_vect)
{
                /* interrupt code here */

                v = 1;          //sets interrupt variable v to 1    
}
```

I am currently testing the behavior of the external interrupts. Whenever an external interrupt is detected a particular code block should be executed.
The interrupt is applied to the INT0 by any logic change.

```
ISR (INT0_vect)
{
    /* interrupt code here */

    v = 1;                              //sets interrupt variable v to 1    
}

int main(void)
{
    USART_Init();
    I2C_init();

    //int a;                                    //test variable

    PORTD |= 0x04;                          //Activate pull up resistor of PD2
    GICR |= (1 << INT0);                    //Enable INT0
    MCUCR |= (1<<ISC00);                    //INT0 is executed on every edge

    sei();  

    unsigned char a;
    a = USART_Receive();

    while(1)
    {
        //TODO:: Please write your application code 

        do 
        {

        } while (v == 0);     //Wait for interrupt

        v = 0;

        _delay_ms(10000);

            //Communication protocol between MCU unit and GUI software application

            //Block 1

            USART_Transmit(0xFF);                           //Header start command
            USART_Transmit(0x00);
            USART_Transmit(0x08);
            USART_Transmit(0x00);
            USART_Transmit(0x09);


            USART_Transmit(0x02);


            USART_Transmit(0x04);

            USART_Transmit(0x05);
            USART_Transmit(0x06);
            USART_Transmit(0x00);

            USART_Transmit(0xFE);                           //Header finish command

            do 
            {
            } while (v == 0);          //Wait for interrupt

            v = 0;              

        _delay_ms(10000);   

            //Block 2

            USART_Transmit(0xFF);                           //Header start command
            USART_Transmit(0x00);
            USART_Transmit(0x01);
            USART_Transmit(0x00);
            USART_Transmit(0x01);


            USART_Transmit(0x01);


            USART_Transmit(0x01);

            USART_Transmit(0x01);
            USART_Transmit(0x01);
            USART_Transmit(0x01);

            USART_Transmit(0xFE);                           //Header finish command




            }

     return 0;
}
```

Testing the code, I can say that the interrupts are recognized and the code is functioning. However, it seems that there is a little bug or logic error.
When the first interrupt occurs (before block 1), block 1 is supposed to be executed. Now, if the second interrupt occurs, the 2nd block should be executed.

I can see this execution sequence in a pre-written GUI application, however, most of the time block 1 (when applying the interrupt) is executed many times after another and than block 2.

It should always be the following sequence: block 1 than block 2 and so on. I think that this is a timing issue. But I cannot debug this problem.

I am also wondering if there is a code in C that tells the program to wait for an external interrupt signal and than continues the program?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Did you define v as volatile int?

Comment: Yes, I defined v as : volatile int v;

Comment: Reading your question again, I got confused. Do you mean block 1 executes more than block 2 does? This is difficult to explain as  both blocks are in sequence. Do you have the source for _delay_ms()?

Comment: I don't know if this could cause issues, but _delay_ms() provides delays up to only 6.5535 seconds (independent from CPU frequency). You probably just won't get the 10s, but its worth mentioning.

Comment: You should also verify that you controller is not performing a reset sometimes for some reason. That would explain why the first block is being executed more often. But I don't see what could cause this in the code you posted.